# Mysql: Query which orders by default and rank (pin/hold up entries?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by, ranking

I have a products table which contains all my products. Those products table gets filled permanently with new products. However, I want to have the possibility to "hold up"/"pin" certain products to a place in the returned query collection.

Means, I want to set something like `rank_index` which contains the number the product should have in the returned query collection.

Example:

```
id     title                rank_index
1      An awesome product
2      Another product      5
3      Baby car
4      Green carpet         2
5      Toy
```

Lets assume the default order would be the `id`. But because the `rank_index` is set for the product with the `id` 4 I would like to get the collection with the following order of ids returned: `1, 4, 3, 5, 2`.

Is this somehow possible to do? The `rank_index` column was just an idea of mine. I mean.. I also could do this on the `php` side and do a normal query which does only include the `products` without an `rank_index` and one which only contains `products` with an `index_rank` and order them manually on the `php` side.

However, because this takes a lot of time and processing power I am looking for a solution which is done by the database... Any ideas?

Btw: I am using Laravel 8 if this makes any difference.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very tricky problem.  If you try the other approach setting consecutive values -- like 2 and 3 -- you will see that they do not work.

There may be simpler ways to solve this. But, here is a brute force approach.

1. It constructs a derived table by enumerating the rows in the original table.
2. It adds into this table (using a `left join`) all the force-ranked values.
3. It joins in the rest of the values by enumerating the empty slots both in `table1` and in the derived table.

So:

```
with recursive n as (
      select row_number() over (order by id) as n
      from table1 t1
     ),
     nid as (
      select n.n, t1.id
      from n left join
           table1 t1
           on t1.rank_index = n.n
     ),
     nids as (
      select n.n, coalesce(n.id, t1.id) as id
      from (select nid.*, sum(nid.id is null) over (order by nid.n) as seqnum
            from nid 
           ) n left join
           (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
            from table1 t1
            where rank_index is null
           ) t1
           on n.seqnum = t1.seqnum
     )
select t1.*
from nids join
     table1 t1
     on t1.id = nids.id
order by nids.n;
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct. However, to my new question I have added the sentence "without recursion" and also I have added that I need a `id` descending order

Comment: I am Very sorry... but when I accepted the answer above I didn't had have the problem of ordering the table `desc` and the answer above is working... but yeah, not for `desc` rows I figured out now...

Comment: @Jan . . . This answer explains that the other two answers are not correcct.

Comment: it works yes... here is an solution without recursion: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/279452/218390

Comment: @Jan . . . You need to set up test data to see if something really works.  I would suggest:  2/3; and 1/2 and 4/5 at the same time.  You have more options with more than 5 slots.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rank_index` if it's not null as the ordering, `id` otherwise:

Since you want the `rank_index` to be ahead of an `id`, a `-0.5` adjustment is made:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY IF(rank_index IS NULL, id, rank_index - 0.5)
```

Comment: And what happens if I want to order it by default not by id but something like a `performance_index` which stands for how "liked" this product is. Just modify your SQL query and use `performance_index` instead of `id`? Because for me it sounds like this only works with `id` as `id` is an incrementing value, `performance_index` wouldn't be.

Comment: order by can be any field in the query or expression derived from it. Its not dependent on `id` being anything other than a something that can be sorted and compared to `rank_index - 0.5` (in this case a number).

Comment: But here now comes a problem... I want to have the newest product always being on top. So ordered the `id` descending... But this leads to the problem that when I give the `rank_index` 2 the product is the second last product... Any idea on how to order it descending while having the product with the `rank_index` 2 at the second place?

Comment: here come a different similar problem? `rank_index + 0.5` and ad `DESC` to the end of the sql for descending. If you want to go more general, rank_index could be a double/float so you can enter `2`, `2.4`, `2.44` provided it stays under 0.5.

Comment: this kinda works... `rank_index` is representing the row number of the row. So, weather ranking `desc` or `asc` I always want to have the row with the row number `2` on the second place from top.... with your corrected solution I have now the table ordered `desc` but the `rank_index` is also `desc`. Means, the row with `rank_index` is the second last row and not the second first row. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Ask a question that fully describes your problem next time, or now, as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IF` clause and to have the correct the number to get te right order, so

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    `id` INTEGER,
    `title` VARCHAR(18),
    `rank_index` INT
);

INSERT INTO table1
    (`id`, `title`, `rank_index`)
VALUES
    ('1', 'An awesome product', NULL),
    ('2', 'Another product', '5'),
    ('3', 'Baby car', NULL),
    ('4', 'Green carpet', '2'),
    ('5', 'Toy', NULL);

SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY IF(rank_index IS NULL, id, rank_index + .01)
```

```
+----+--------------------+------------+
| id | title              | rank_index |
+----+--------------------+------------+
| 1  | An awesome product | NULL       |
| 4  | Green carpet       | 2          |
| 3  | Baby car           | NULL       |
| 5  | Toy                | NULL       |
| 2  | Another product    | 5          |
+----+--------------------+------------+
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2330e03ed709fdbce0d0d6887552b00)*